# How can I prevent from applying blur Filter Image on resize?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to resize an image in my app. The issue is that Android automatically applies a filter that blurs the pixels. How can I prevent that from happening and instead see the Individual Pixels. As in Pixelated. Im using the ValueAnimator to increase the size of RelativeLayout that has an image set as Background.

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(2000, 200000);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

        int state = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        screenX = state;
        screenY = state;

        myContent.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(screenX, screenY));

    }
});
animator.setDuration(2000);
animator.start();
```

Example of What I mean

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys after searching for a while I found a solution to this.

http://www.41post.com/4241/programming/android-disabling-anti-aliasing-for-pixel-art

The word I was missing that would have helped me find an answer faster was Anti-Aliasing which has to be dissabled